# Facing issue while creating helm chart

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

```
replicas: {{ len .Values.workerZones }}
```

Here I am getting the value for replicas on the basis of no of entries in workZones label in another yaml file values.yaml

```
workerZones:
  - zoneName: dummy-zone-1a
    zone: a
```

but while creating helm chart I am getting this error

```
kustomize build config/default > ./helm/iq-backup-restore-operator/templates/iq-backup-restore-operator.yaml
Error: map[string]interface {}(nil): yaml: invalid map key: map[string]interface {}{"len .Values.workerZones":""}
Makefile:110: recipe for target 'helm-chart' failed
make: *** [helm-chart] Error 1**
```

I am not sure how to resolve this one. Can anyone help ?

I tried putting `{{ len .Values.workerZones }}` as  `"{{ len .Values.workerZones }}"` this works but it gives me string value as '1'. I need the value of `replicas` to be an integer. I am not sure how to convert this string into an integer.